# Spring Cloud Contract DSL verify date format

Tags: jodatime, spring-cloud-contract

How can I verify the date format in a contract?  I ran into an issue a while ago where my service inherited an object mapper that changed the format of the dates my service returns from milliseconds to timestamps.  I'm trying to write a contract that would catch the date format change.  Here's what I put in my contract:

```
response {
    status 200
    body(
            time: 1505276760077L
    )
}
```

Here's what I'm playing with in my object mapper:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());

    /*
    uncommenting this cause DateTime format to change from 
    milliseconds to timestamp
    i.e., 1505276760077 changes to 2017-09-13T04:26:00.077Z
    Either way, the test passes
     */
    // objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature
               .WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

    return objectMapper;
}
```

The test passes regardless of the format the date is in.  Is there some way to make the test fail when the format changes?

I have a sample project here if that helps: https://github.com/rtteal/consumer-driven-contacts-demo

**Update:**

I tried updating my contract to use a regex, but that still doesn't cause my test to fail when changing the object mapper.

```
response {
    status 200
    body(
            time: $(regex('[0-9]{13}'))
    )
}
```

This is the relevant part of the generated test:

```
assertThatJson(parsedJson).field("['time']").matches("[0-9]{13}");
```

The test seems to be ignoring the object mapper config.  Do I need to do something to make it pick up the object mapper when the test is run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex for dates (http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Dalston.SR3/#_regular_expressions). Then a valid date will get generated for you. You could also set the low value of the `priority` field (that means a higher priority). If you need to create a separate contract for an invalid date, what you can do is create such a pair for date that will match `nonBlank()` value. Set a higher value of the `priority` field (that means a lower priority). That way you'll have 2 contracts for the same URL that verify 2 behaviors. 1) Valid date, 2) invalid date

UPDATE:

You are using MockMvc with a standalone setup. That means that it ignores any context configuration that you have. If you want the bean that you have created to be taken into account, here (https://github.com/rtteal/consumer-driven-contacts-demo/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/DemoBase.java#L17), use the webAppContextSetup method. Check this page - https://piotrminkowski.wordpress.com/2017/04/26/testing-java-microservices/ for an example.

Comment: Hi Marcin, thanks for the suggestion.  I updated my question with an attempt at implementing your suggested solution, but it's still not failing when I change the date format.  Can you provide an example or clarify what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Would it be a problem for you to upload also the generated test and update the question?

Comment: The generated test in case where you set the regular expression of the response and no the current one that you have there with fixed value of time

Comment: I added the relevant part from the generated test case.

Comment: You are using `MockMvc` with a standalone setup. That means that it ignores any context configuration that you have. If you want the bean that you have created to be taken into account, here (https://github.com/rtteal/consumer-driven-contacts-demo/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/DemoBase.java#L17), use the `webAppContextSetup` method. Check this page - https://piotrminkowski.wordpress.com/2017/04/26/testing-java-microservices/ for an example.

Comment: Thanks @marcin-grzejszczak, that got me headed in the right direction.  Switching to `webAppContextSetup` and adding my objectMapper Bean got it working the way I was expecting.  I still don't quite follow the importance of `priority`, but I'll read the docs on that to see if I can figure it out.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Sure thing.  I would up-vote, but I don't have reputation yet :(.